# Simple Django filter query: group by primary key?

Tags: django, django-models, django-piston

I am running a `filter` query in Django with `range`. I thought `filter` always returned a queryset that was grouped by the primary key, but it seems not.

These are my models:

```
class MCode(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=16)
class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key=True, db_index=True)
    mcode = models.ForeignKey(MCode, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
class Review(models.Model):
    review_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True, db_index=True) 
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, db_index=True) 
    rating = models.IntegerField() 
    time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
```

And this is my code:

```
mcode = 'M83'
base = Product.objects
tcode_obj = MCode.objects.filter(code=mcode.upper())
return base.filter(tcode=tcode_obj, 
                   review__time__range=[date_from, date_to])
```

I'm getting five results, but three of them have the same primary key. It looks like I'm getting a result for each `review`, not each `product`.

Does anyone know how could I group these `products` by ID, and annotate with the count of the attached `reviews`?

Comment: When you say "group" do you mean "sort"? "Group by" is a totally different concept.

Comment: I just want a result for each product, not for each review. Maybe I should do this on the client side, but I was wondering if it was possible with Django.

Comment: That does the trick! Thank you. If you want to submit it as an answer, I'll accept it - you may think it's too basic to be an answer, but it might help other newbies searching....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select based on something that could match multiple times, such as `Product` with `Review`s during a range of time, each match is added to the queryset, even if it's a duplicate of an item already there. There's actually times where you might want this behavior, but if you need to limit the queryset to just unique items, use `.distinct()` at the end of your query. Getting duplicates is also common when using logical ORs in your query, so be aware of times you do that and remember to use `.distinct()` there as well.